# Screen keeps rendering after initializing Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

So I'm trying to implement authentication using Firebase and I got an error saying

> [core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()

I found a way to deal with the error by adding the following code to my main.dart file:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(StockApp());
}
```

The method to check if the user is logged in is as follows:

```
isLoggedIn() async {
    _auth.authStateChanges().listen((user) {
      if (user != null)
        Navigator.push(
            context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home()));
      else
        Navigator.push(
            context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Login()));
    });
  }

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.isLoggedIn();
  }
```

The error is gone but now my login page keeps rendering endlessly.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here you are navigating to the screen on listening the stream so it will continuously pushing the widget to the stack.Instead of this you can use

```
User? _user;
isLoggedIn() async {
    _auth.authStateChanges().listen((user) {
      _user=user;
      setState((){})
      
    });

    if (user != null)
        Navigator.push(
            context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home()));
      else
        Navigator.push(
            context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Login()));
  }
```

Comment: I'm getting a new error now: 
'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 5082 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap this.isLoggedIn method inside addPostFrameCallback as

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_){
     this.isLoggedIn()
});
```

Comment: That didn't work. I'm still getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working demo.Try with this code.

```
class DemoPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const DemoPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DemoPage> createState() => _DemoPageState();
}

class _DemoPageState extends State<DemoPage> {
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      isLoggedIn();
    });
  }

  User? _user;
  isLoggedIn() async {
    _auth.authStateChanges().listen((user) {
      _user = user;
      setState(() {});
    });

    if (_user != null) {
      Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Home()));
    } else {
      Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Login()));
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Home'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Login extends StatelessWidget {
  const Login({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Login'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I still see the  'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 5082 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true. error